# change mode of a file for a specific group in ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, file-permissions, ubuntu-18.04, user-permissions

The current set of permissions for `node.log` is

> -rwxrwxr-x  1 syslog adm       0 Aug  7 16:03 node.log

I would like it to become

> -rwxrwxrwx  1 syslog adm       0 Aug  7 16:03 node.log

I tried `$ sudo chmod g+w node.log` to no avail.

I am logged into an account with root acces through `sudo`.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct command is

```
$ sudo chmod o+w node.log
```

OR

```
$ sudo chmod 777 node.log
```